# generating a random dice roll using LFSR

Tags: c++, random

I have code that generates a random number using a Left Feedback Shift Register that I got off the internet:

```
#define POLY_MASK_32 0xB4BCD35C
#define POLY_MASK_31 0x7A5BC2E3

#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned int uint;

uint lfsr32, lfsr31;

int shift_lfsr(uint *lfsr,  uint polymonial_mask)
{
    int feedback;

    feedback = *lfsr & 1;
    *lfsr >>= 1;
    if (feedback == 1)
        *lfsr ^= polymonial_mask;
    return *lfsr;
}

void init_lfsrs(void)
{
    lfsr32 = 0xABCDE; //seed values
    lfsr31 = 0x23456789;
}

int get_random(void)
{
    /*this random number generator shifts the 32-bit LFSR twice before XORing
      it with the 31-bit LFSR. the bottom 16 bits are used for the random number*/
    shift_lfsr(&lfsr32, POLY_MASK_32);
    return(shift_lfsr(&lfsr32, POLY_MASK_32) ^ shift_lfsr(&lfsr31, POLY_MASK_31));
}

void main(void)
{
    int random_value[10];

    init_lfsrs();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        random_value[i] = get_random();
        std::cout << random_value[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I dont fully unerstand whats going on here but I know that it will produce a 32-bit number in a non repeating sequence.  I think it then takes the first 16-bits to be the number displayed.

What I am wanting to do is produce a number between 1-6 from this...anyone able to help out?

**Edit** I was also going to change the 2 seed values to an srand(time) rand() number so that it doesn't start the same every time.  is this right and how would i go about that?

Comment: Since C++11, C++ have very good [pseudo-random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) functionality in the standard library. Check the example code for [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: I have been asked to implement a random number as random as I can.  Was going to use random.org but was having issues with that and dont want to have to have an internet connection.  This seemed like a good way to go about it...then i got stuck

Comment: Actually, all "random" numbers generated by software aren't random. They're just pseudo-random. If you really want to create fully random number, you have to use hardware generators. If you need software, C rand() function or any other function is a quite good solution.

Comment: Making good pseudo-random number generators is **hard**. For the hardcore theory, I recommend chapter 3 of [The Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming). For a simpler solution, I recommend http://xkcd.com/221/... ;)

Comment: As for the use of `rand` to seed your generator, the more random the seeds are the better of course, but then it's also harder to predict the values when debugging.

Comment: `void main` doesn’t compile on my compiler. `main`’s return type must be `int`.

Comment: @tim, If you want to mix random-number generators it's usually best to mix two different types.  LFSRs like yours are generally only used to generate one bit per iteration.  If you return the whole state word then you have a 50:50 chance that the value in one stage will be exactly half that in the previous stage, which can be a bit too predictable.  Google 'marsaglia' for several popular generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce a random number between 1 and 6, do this

```
 int myRandomNumber = 1 + (random_value[i] % 6);
```

Why does this work?

```
random_value[i] % 6
```

will produce a value between 0 and 5, so we add 1 to it to get a value between 1 and 6.

Read up on the modulus operator

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

In general, to produce a random number in some closed set [a, b], you would do

```
int myRandomNumber = a + ( random_value[i] % (b - a + 1) )
```

Comment: This is actually a quite bad (biased) way of producing random numbers unless the maximum of `random_value` happens to be divisible by 6. Here’s an explanation why: http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx

Comment: It's only very slightly biased.  For most purposes it's fine.  (For the case of 6, the ratio for the first 3 values vs the last 3 values for 32-bit ints is 715,827,883 vs 715,827,882, or only about 140 billionths of a percent more likely to give you a 1 than a 5.)

Comment: In fact, no matter how you divide up the range from 0 .. 2^32-1, you _will_ have some bias, unless you simply throw out a range of return values from `get_random()` so you're subdividing 6 exactly-equal ranges.